# From visa to naturalization

Tags: united-states, immigration

I have found an [arrival record](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=nypl&h=3023011971&ti=0&indiv=try&gss=pt&ssrc=pt_t20889399_p20296828381_kpidz0q3d20296828381z0q26pgz0q3d32768z0q26pgplz0q3dpid) (Ancestry.com) for Annelise Morgenthau, age 20, arriving in New York on 26 Nov 1947 on the ship *Marine Jumper*. Her visa number is given as QIV 6631 (issued on 26 Sep 1947 in London), and an annotation on the second sheet implies that she is intending to become a permanent resident. She is coming to join a friend or relative who is listed as F. Kahn:

[image]

Kahn is Annelise's mother's maiden name, which gives me more confidence that this is the right person. Perhaps she is coming to join her uncle...

Unfortunately, I cannot find any other trace of her in the US, and would like to explore the possibility that I can find her naturalization papers through the visa number and date of issue.

What is the right way to proceed? How do I find a naturalization request or other pertinent information based on the entry visa number?

Answer (score 3):

I found a lot on my grandfather at [The USCIS Genealogy Program](http://www.uscis.gov/portal/site/uscis/menuitem.eb1d4c2a3e5b9ac89243c6a7543f6d1a/?vgnextchannel=d21f3711ca5ca110VgnVCM1000004718190aRCRD&vgnextoid=d21f3711ca5ca110VgnVCM1000004718190aRCRD), but you may have some hurdles:

1. There's not much available yet after 1944.
2. Annelise Morgenthau is under 100 years old, so you'd need a death certificate to access her records.
3. She had to be in the U.S. for two years before filing any formal intention. If she married a U.S. citizen within that time, she'd have no need to file.

Comment: For all I know, she is still alive. Ironically, that's one of the reasons for trying to locate her. I suppose I could try to find her in the New York marriages, if that's available for the late 1940s-early 1950s.